# What do the callback functions used by a promise return?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to figure out JavaScript promises. I have read multiple documents on the subject including [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Perhaps I am missing something obvious but I cannot find the answer to the following question. What do the callback functions used by then and catch return?

This information is not clearly stated anywhere in these pages.

The following code sample comes from the [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) page.

```
createAudioFileAsync(audioSettings).then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

If my question was answered on that page there would be a sentence similar to the following very near this code sample.

`successCallback` is a method that returns {answer to question}. However, nowhere on either page is such a sentence to be found.

The following paragraph does not answer this question.

> The methods [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then),
> [Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch), and
> [Promise.prototype.finally()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) are used to
> associate further action with a promise that
> becomes settled. As these methods return promises,
> they can be chained.

This paragraph says the [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then),
[Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch), and [Promise.prototype.finally()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) methods themselves "return promises". It says nothing about the callback methods.

The following comment in the Common mistakes section that suggests that the `successCallback` method is supposed to return a Promise.

```
// Forgot to return promise from inner chain + unnecessary nesting
```

But other information in that same page seems to contradict this.

Consider the following code block.

```
const listOfIngredients = [];
doSomething()
  .then((url) => fetch(url))
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    listOfIngredients.push(data);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(listOfIngredients);
  });
```

Some of the success callbacks have a clear return, the ones that use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but the others do not appear to return anything.

The [Example with diverse situations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#example_with_diverse_situations) example only adds to the confusion. The `promiseGetWord` method clearly returns a Promise but the `determineParity` method returns something else. If the answer to my question is that it returns a Promise, how is "return { value, isOdd };" the same as returning a Promise?

Comment: `.then`/`.catch` return a promise. The callback that you pass to them can return whatever it wants, and its return value will be passed as argument to the next callback function in the chain.

Comment: @deceze I am certain you think you answered my question but you did not. You say ".then/.catch return a promise". How does tbe following return anything?

.then((data) => {
    listOfIngredients.push(data);
  })
  
This is not an arrow function. And the word return is nowhere to be found.

Comment: The callback to that `.then` function indeed returns nothing. But the `.then(…)` function itself **returns another promise.** That’s why you can append another `.then` to it. There’s two separate levels to this: the actual *promise objects* returned from `.then(…)`, and the *values returned from and passed to callback functions* within this promise chain.

Comment: @deceze Thank you. I think I finally figured it out.

Comment: Good to hear. It's almost trivial in its simplicity, but if you're thinking about it the wrong way, it makes no sense. Kinda like a zen koan. Promise objects have `.then`/`.catch` methods. Promise objects will call the callbacks you attach using those `.then`/`.catch` methods based on whether the promise fulfils or rejects. `.then`/`.catch` methods return a new promise object. The callbacks you give those methods will receive the promise's resolved value, and whatever they return becomes the next promise's resolved value.